# Removing msvcp90d.dll dependancy from Windows binary

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I have a dll that I distribute that will not run on some windows OS. Using dependancy walker I discover msvcp90d.dll missing on these systems. I *DO NOT* want any run time dependancies that require the C++ redistributable, and since the application that calls the DLL is not written in C++, it does not have any dependancy on the C++ redistributable.

I am guessing the I left the DEBUG option in the linker preferences on when I compiled the dll which is why it needs msvcp90d.dll?

ADDED:
Appologies, I pasted the wrong dll name in my original question.... too many hours in front of the monitor...

THe dll is a third party dll that I did not write compiled by me in VS2008.

Comment: msvcp90d? Looks like you left debug on as well as used dynamic linking. I hope you are building this DLL in a repeatable manner using an msbuild script? I hope you aren't building from the IDE!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSVCP90 is nothing to do with debug (that'd be msvcp90d). You can remove your dependency by switching the compiler to /MT (instead of /MD). You also need to ensure that every static library you link to was also compiled /MT.

I recommend against building apps /MT because it has a significant negative effect on system performance and makes servicing take longer in the event of a security issue with the CRT.

Finally, note that /MT means that your CRT is private. So you must ensure that CRT/STL types don't pass across your DLL boundary.

Martyn

Comment: "Significant negative effect on system performance" Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Appologies, I pasted the wrong dll name in my original question

Comment: @David - if everyone loads msvcp90 (which is in winsxs, generally), the OS will only spend one set of pages for every process. If you static link, the same code is being loaded lots of times, wasting lots of pages. The overall impact is significant for each additional static-link person.

Comment: Well, it might be significant. Most of the time it won't be. I guess the selfish option is to use static link to make redist easy!

Comment: @Mike - In that case, your problem is indeed debug. If the DLL is from a 3rd party, tell them to fix it. Because redistributing msvcr90d.dll is not permitted by the EULA.

Comment: @David - this perspective is wrong. I've seen lots of measurments that validatethi.Lots of users have small machines, and using a static-CRT is just the wrong choice for almost all situations. The complexity of a redist is pretty low, and the upside is absolutely worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Your options as I see them:

1. Compile the DLL with the /MT option to use static linking to the C runtime.
2. Continue with dynamic linking to the runtime, but distribute the C runtime with your app.

Comment: +1 for static linking I left that option out as I rarely want the bloat or other issues that come with /MT

Comment: @AJG85 I love static linking. I hate redistributing runtimes. Horses for courses as we say.

Comment: I love static linking too. Appologies, I pasted the wrong dll name in my original question

Answer (score 1):

It needs MSVCP90.dll because the dll was compiled with Visual Studio 2008 most likely. That is the release runtime.  The short answer is if you don't want C++ runtime dependencies don't use C++ libraries or applications.

However you can do any of the following to solve your problem:

1. Install the redistributable to the target system to satisfy the dependency
2. Remove the dependency on that dll from your application
3. Recompile the dll against the version of VC you prefer that is already present on the target system

Comment: Appologies, I pasted the wrong dll name in my original question

Comment: Ah then simply compiling the DLL in release may be enough for you or go the static route as others have suggested. Most windows systems will have the release runtime redistributables already.